# Mlt Melt add audio track to video

Tags: audio, video, command-line, video-editing, mlt

I have several video clips with different lengthes.
And there is audio track I want to mix over those clips.

I use this:

```
melt original.mp4 -audio-track preview.mp3 -transition mix
```

If `preview.mp3` is longer than `original.mp4`
then when  video ends the mixing still plays mp3 until the end.

**The question** is how to mix audio to clips that are not longer than audio track that way as to cut audio track at the point when video clips ends.

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:-
melt original.mp4 in = clipin out=clipout -track preview.mp3 in=clipin out=clipout

it run the video parallel with audio.

thanks,

Comment: what are clipin and clipout? the video clips i use all have differenet lengthes

Comment: Usually i dont know the size of clip so couldn't user in=, out=